# Insufficient Storage on changing default install location

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb

After downloading an APK file from Play Store. It always prompts "Insufficient Storage" dialog.

I changed the default install location into external memory(SD card) using adb command

```
adb shell pm set-install-location 2
```

There is a room for both Internal (400mb free) and External memory(8GB free).

I am running on an Android Kitkat 4.4;
I am not rooted anyway. I don't want to void my warranty

Answer (score 1):

By default I think apps are only installable to phone storage. The developer has to specifically allow the app to be installed to external storage (SD card or emulated SD card storage). 
The ADB shell command you have used is only designed for use during development (see http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). It may be that despite issuing this command the system is still trying to install to internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using sets the external memory as the default install location not the default download location. The possibility of external memory as default download location is entirely up to the developer of your mobile firmware.

Answer (score -1):

Install Terminal Emulator app and run the "pm" part of the command directly in your phone. works just the same, without the trouble to install SDK and all.