# Can't install apps Waze/Walmart but can install other apps

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, apk

I'm struggling to figure this out.  I've got an HTC Evo V running KK using link2d.  Link2sd shows internal (/data) as having 43% Free (517MB of 1.15GB).  I can install some apps, but I am not able to install Waze or Walmart apps.  I get an 'Insufficient storage' error.  I've even tried using adb to upload the Waze apk and get the same error.  I've also tried setting my install location to external (abd shell pm set-install-location 2) but this has no effect.

Can someone tell me what might be going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insufficient Storage on changing default install location](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/insufficient-storage-on-changing-default-install-location)